# OData multiple expands and filter

Tags: odata

I've read through OData documentation and various Stack Overflow questions and can't seem to figure out the syntax for an OData query that involves multiple `$expand` and a `$filter` statement.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
https://odata-api.blah.com/accounts?$expand=company&$filter=company/name eq 'Nebcorp'&$expand=company/company_plan
```

Through the accounts table, I am going through a pair of navigation properties to expand the company and company plan tables. Doing the above query (or variations of it) results in a 500 error.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve so here a few things that might help:

You can add multiple filters by using a comma for example: 
`$expand=Company,Friends`

You can expand nested properties with bracket, like this:
`$expand=Company($expand=company_plan)`

You can filter on any of these expansions, for example, if instead of Company, you had a collection property of all companies, you might do something like this:

`$expand=Companies($expand=company_plan;$filter=Current eq 'y')`

So I think that you will want one of these two URLs, depending on whether you want "all accounts for company Nebcorp" - `https://.../accounts?$expand=company($expand=company_plan)&$filter=company/name eq 'Nebcorp'`

Or whether you want "all accounts, expanding the company details and plans but only for Nebcorp" - `https://.../accounts?$expand=company($expand=company_plan;$filter=name eq 'Nebcorp')`