# How to Split OData multi-level expand query string in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, odata

I have a URL: *`Expand=User($select=Firstname,Lastname),Organisation,Contract($Expand=MyOrganisation($select=Name,Status),Organisation),List`*

I need to split this string in the below format:

- `User($select=Firstname,Lastname)`
- `Organisation`
- `Contract($Expand=MyOrganisation($select=Name,Status),Organisation)`
- `List`

How to achieve this functionality in C#?

Comment: Do you have any reasons to have a single parameter instead of 4? Like user=User($select=Firstname,Lastname)&organisation=Organisation, etc.

Comment: yes a need for odata conversion.

Comment: OData is the thing here "$select=Firstname,Lastname" and it doesn't require to put everything in one string

Comment: Odata supports multiple level filters and expand functions Ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525409/odata-multiple-expands-and-filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You not only need to split the string but also keep track of the parentheses while splitting. This is not possible with just plain old regex. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses).
However, the splitting can be achieved with some advanced RegEx; .NET fortunately supports [balancing groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#balancing-group-definitions) using which you can keep track of the parentheses. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7899205/11455105) was quite helpful in coming up with a solution.  For readability, I have split the regex into multiple lines and used `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`:

```
string url = "User($select=Firstname,Lastname),Organisation,Contract($Expand=MyOrganisation($select=Name,Status),Organisation),List";
Regex rgx = new Regex(
               @"(.+?)
                (
                    (
                        \(
                            (?:
                                [^()]
                                |
                                (?'open'\()
                                |
                                (?'close-open'\))
                            )+
                            (?(open)(?!))
                        \)
                    )
                    ,
                    |
                    ,
                    |
                    \b$
                )", 
               RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

foreach(var match in rgx.Matches(url))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{match.Groups[1]} {match.Groups[3]}"); 
}
```

The field will be available as `match.Groups[1]` and the parameters, if any will be available as `match.Groups[3]`(this will be an empty string if there are no parameters). You can access `match.Groups[0]` to get the entire group.

#### Regex Breakdown

| Regex | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `(.+?)` | Non-greedily match one or more characters |
| `\(` and `\)` | Match an actual `(` and `)` |
| `[^()]` | Match any character that is not a `(` or `)` |
| `(?'open'\()` | Create a named group with the name "open" and match a `(` character |
| `(?'close-open\))` | Create a group "close" and assign the interval between "open" and "close" to "close" and delete group "open" |
| `(?(open)(?!))` | Assert if the "open" group is not deleted |
| `(?:[^()]|(?'open'\()|(?'close-open'\)))+` | Create a non-capturing group and match one or more characters that match one of the expressions between `|` |

Comment: List will be not part of result and match.Groups[2] will crash

Comment: @BorisSokolov Thanks, I've found a fix to add `\b$` to match the last word. Also `match.Groups[2]` won't crash, it would just be an empty group. If you check the value of `match.Groups.Count`, it is always 3 since there are two groups in the pattern.

Comment: @SureshSankar that's because how I've formatted it: Change the `Console.WriteLine` to `Console.WriteLine($"{match.Groups[0]}{match.Groups[1]}"` to get the format in the question.

Comment: @SureshSankar Check the updated answer. And specify what exactly isn't working correctly

Comment: @AmalK Console.WriteLine($"{match.Groups[0]}{match.Groups[1]}") i was changed and verify still its not correct

Comment: Expected: Field: Contract Parameters: $Expand=MyOrganisation($select=Name,Status),Organisation)

Comment: @AmalK In contract string split not expected please give me the idea.

Comment: @SureshSankar Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Prefect RegEx explanation :)

Comment: @AmalK  and Boris Sokolov That's working fine. Thanks a lot for your supports.

Answer (score 2):

More likely you have to use an [ODataLib](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/odatalib) with in-built [URI Parser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/odatalib/use-uri-parser)

```
Uri requestUri = new Uri("Products?$select=ID&$expand=ProductDetail" +
                         "&$filter=Categories/any(d:d/ID%20gt%201)&$orderby=ID%20desc" +
                         "&$top=1&$count=true&$search=tom",
                         UriKind.Relative);
ODataUriParser parser = new ODataUriParser(model, serviceRoot, requestUri);
SelectExpandClause expand = parser.ParseSelectAndExpand(); // parse $select, $expand
FilterClause filter = parser.ParseFilter();                // parse $filter
OrderByClause orderby = parser.ParseOrderBy();             // parse $orderby
SearchClause search = parser.ParseSearch();                // parse $search
long? top = parser.ParseTop();                             // parse $top
long? skip = parser.ParseSkip();                           // parse $skip
bool? count = parser.ParseCount();                         // parse $count
```

Adding the RegExp option (the fixed version of what Amal has provided below)

```
    string url = "User($select=Firstname,Lastname),Organisation,Contract($Expand=MyOrganisation($select=Name,Status),Organisation),List";

    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(.+?)(?:(\(.*?\)),|,)");

    foreach (var match in rgx.Matches($"{url},"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.ToString()[..^1]);
    }
```

Comment: we don't have a model we are using dynamic or Jobject. I was tried it's not working without a model.

Comment: A manual parsing would be problematic as you don't have a specific delimiter (comma is used for multiple purposes). So if you know for sure that there is ")," statement, then "," and ")," afterwards - you can go with IndexOf() and substrigns

Comment: That's a nice way of using indices and ranges. Note that they are only supported since C# 8.0